# PySpark Reading Multiple Files in Parallel

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have the below requirement in my project and we are attempting to use PySpark for data processing.

We used to receive sensor data in the form of Parquet files for each vehicle and its one file per vehicle. The file has a lot of sensors but its structured data in Parquet format. Avg file size is 200MB per file.

Assume i received files as below in one batch and ready for processing.

**Train     FileSize          Date**

X1        210MB        05-Sep-18 12:10 AM

X1        280MB        05-Sep-18 05:10 PM

Y1        220MB        05-Sep-18 04:10 AM

Y1        241MB        05-Sep-18 06:10 PM

At the end of the processing, I need to receive one aggregated .csv file from every source file or one master file with aggregated data for all these vehicle.

I am aware that HDFS default block size is 128MB and each file will be split into 2 blocks. May i know how can i accomplish this requirement using PySpark? Is it possible to process all these files in parallel?

Please let me know your thoughts

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar problem, and it seems that I found a way:
1. Get a list of files
2.parallelize this list (distribute among all nodes)
3.write a function that reads content of all files from the portion of the big list that was distributed to the node
4.run it with mapPartition, then collect the result as a list, each element is a collected content of each file.
Fot files stored on AWS s3 and json files:

```
def read_files_from_list(file_list):
#reads files from  list
#returns content as list of strings, 1 json per string ['{}','{}',...]
   out=[]
   for x in file_list:
      content = sp.check_output([ 'aws', 's3', 'cp', x, '-']) # content of the file. x here is a full path: 's3://bucket/folder/1.json'
      out.append(content)   
   return out #content of all files from the file_list as list of strings, 1 json per string ['{}','{}',...]


file_list=['f1.json','f2.json',...]
    ps3="s3://bucket/folder/"
    full_path_chunk=[ps3 + f for f in file_list] #makes list  of strings, with full path for each file
    n_parts = 100
    rdd1 = sc.parallelize(full_path_chunk, n_parts ) #distribute files among nodes
    list_of_json_strings = rdd1.mapPartitions(read_files_from_list).collect()
```

Then, if necessary, you can create spark dataframe like this:

```
rdd2=sc.parallelize(list_of_json_strings) #this is a trick! via http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#json-datasets
df_spark=sqlContext.read.json(rdd2)
```

The function read_files_from_list is just an example, it should be changed to read files from hdfs using python tools.
Hope this helps :)

Comment: thank you lugger1.. quick question - Does sc.parallelize(full_path_chunk, n_parts ) split file list into 100 chunks and send as 100 partitions to the cluster nodes?

Comment: Yes, it distributes 100 parts of the full list among the nodes, so if you have fixed number of nodes , let's say 4 (each with 8 cores), instead of 100 use 4*8*3 = 96 there for better performance.

Comment: In the function read_files_from_list(file_list), what is sp? @lugger1

Comment: sp is subprocess. Somewhere before there is 'import subprocess as sp' line.

Comment: Hi @lugger1 will "read_files_from_list" work in case parquet file?

Comment: Hi @lugger one more thing. Is it downloading each and every file from s3 and then reading the content?

Comment: I didn't work with parquet files, so I can't tell you much about it. The general principle it the same (get list of files from s3, split it among nodes, read files, collect the result), details might be different. "read_files_from_list" is a function that works on each node, and downloads a portion of files (this portion is in full_path_chunk, so it's not each and every file from s3, but just part of the full list of files we need) that was split and delivered into each node with parallelize().

Answer (score 1):

You can put all input files in the same directory then you can pass path of directory to spark. You can also use globbing like `/data_dir/*.csv`.

Comment: Hi Hamza.. yes i have seen some answers that i can place all the files in a dir. If i do so, will i be able to process every file in parallel using Spark in case i want to generate .csv file as output for each i/p file?

Comment: I think spark handles it. Spark will partition them to workers. Each worker will handle its own partition. There is no need think parallelism while using spark data structures.

Comment: So, all files in the directory will be loaded in RDD during processing and partitioned across the nodes in the cluster. Hence, Spark treats all the files inside the dir as a single file. Is that right?

Comment: Yes. You can also repartition or apply function to each partition if you looking for that.

Comment: one last question.. bit confused.. What if i want to process each file in one node across the cluster..? say i have 4 files and i want it to be processed by 4 diff nodes in the cluster by making every file as a partition

Comment: You can create file name rdd like `['path1','path2','path3',]`. then read and map seperatly. Or Im not sure but you can repatition to number of files.

Comment: @AngiSenYes, it treats them as a single dataframe

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered similar situation recently.
You can pass a list of CSVs with their paths to spark read api like `spark.read.json(input_file_paths)` ([source](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv)). This will load all the files in a single dataframe and all the transformations eventually performed will be done in parallel by multiple executors depending on your spark config.